# Android Studio Java - looking solution to reset Previous Activity in passed activity

Tags: java, android

Assume I have 2 activities called "ActivitiyA" and "ActivitiyB".

I have an intent that enables me to go "activityB" from "activityA". In one of the function in "activityB" will be called "finish()" to send the user back to "ActivityA". Before showing activity A, I would like to reset 2 EditText from "ActivityA".

In order to satisfy above scenario what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't how you use tags. when you make a question, use the appropriate tags `android` and `java`, dont just use android studio, because android studio is an IDE, meaning that it _helps_ you to code. but you're not asking about a feature of the IDE

Comment: please explore startActivityForResult. you must be using startActivity to go from one activity to other, use startActivityForRestult instead

Answer (score 1):

In `ActivityA`, launch `ActivityB` for result using `startActivityForResult` and check for `onActivityResult` to clear `edittext`

```
val REQUEST_CODE = 1234
startActivityForResult(Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java), REQUEST_CODE)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode : Int, data: Intent){  
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
     if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {  
         //clear or reset edittext here
     }  
}
```

In `ActivityB`, before finishing do below

```
setResult(1234, Intent())
finish()
```

Comment: are you sure this way is still supported ? i believe [it is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java)

Comment: it is still supported but will be deprecated soon and there are new ActivityResult API's, which is way cleaner using kotlin first, but this works too based on your target sdk, more details on new implementation https://proandroiddev.com/is-onactivityresult-deprecated-in-activity-results-api-lets-deep-dive-into-it-302d5cf6edd

Comment: yeah i was just asking out of personal interest, i haven't used startActivityForResult in a long time so i was wondering if this is still valid or not

Answer (score 1):

Just define an `interface`, if you need to call back before `.onActivityResult()`:

```
// Java
public interface Callbacks {
   void resetThoseInputFileds();
}

// Kotlin
interface Callbacks {
   fun resetThoseInputFileds()
}
```

and then let `ActivityA` implement it - so that it can be called from `ActivityB`